# How do I add a role to new members discord

Tags: c#, discord

I've tried different things but they never work. I tried to add the code to my new user joined task

```
public async Task AnnounceJoinedUser(SocketGuildUser user) //welcomes New Players
{
    var channel = Client.GetChannel(447147292617736203) as SocketTextChannel; //gets channel to send message in
    await channel.SendMessageAsync("Welcome " + user.Mention + " to the server! Have a great time"); //Welcomes the new user
}
```

But I dont know how to add a role to new user

Comment: Docs say you need a PUT request on /guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}/roles/{role.id} https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member-role
But its hard to guess what you already did ..

Comment: I managed to get 

`await user.AddRoleAsync();`

But I dont know how to get the role I want to add to them.

Comment: Well, i don't know that api. I just looked into the docs i posted above...
Maybe search for some basics about 'REST API', since it seems to be one. Normally it works as follows:
`GET`: get a single record.
`LIST`: get a list of records (here they seem to use GET instead and use specific routes: .../members gets all and .../memers/{member.id} on record.
`POST` or `PUT`: add a new record, wicht method depends. look it up ;)
`PATCH`: modify a record
`DELETE`: you guess it ...
So, you will need to call `GET/guilds/{guild.id}/roles`

Comment: Ol Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the role from the guild that the user joined in first, then add the role to the user using `user.AddRoleAsync()`.

```
private async Task UserJoined(SocketGuildUser socketGuildUser) {
    ulong roleID = 123; //Some hard-coded roleID
    var role = socketGuildUser.Guild.GetRole(roleID);
    await socketGuildUser.AddRoleAsync(role);

    //Without ID...
    string roleName = "The role name to add to user"; //Or some other property
    //Get the list of roles in the guild.
    var guildRoles = socketGuildUser.Guild.Roles;
    //Loop through the list of roles in the guild.
    foreach(var guildRole in guildRoles) {
        //If the current iteration of role matches the rolename
        if(guildRole.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            //Assign the role to the user.
            await socketGuildUser.AddRoleAsync(guildRole);
            //Exit Loop.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```